# How can the server trigger an event on the client?

Tags: php

How does a server trigger an event on client? For example how in Gmail a popup is appeared when you receive am IM?

Comment: read about xmpp Protocol.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol & server push http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to contact the server, possibly coupled with [long-polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling) to get faster response times (at the price of holding a connection open).

Answer (score -1):

You may use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to achieve a similar effect.

AJAX uses Javascript code to regularly and silently request data from the server. This data may then be used by Javascript to perform some actions.

Comment: How come the question and answers on this page get voted down?

Comment: I had mistakenly given -1 to you. wanted to give to another anwser which had used " run a periodic jQuery ".. but you have to improve you anwser

Comment: Did you mean client should send frequently ajax-request to server and to be informed from server changes and commands, it is not a practical solution.

Comment: xmpp, sockets is ONE of the correct answer. u cannot use ajax if u want to trigger event from server or want a chat application

Comment: @dhpratik [Google search for "ajax chat application in php"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ajax+chat+application+in+php) returns lots of examples. A chat application can indeed use Ajax to regularly request new data from server.